# Почему я не могу подключиться к серверу?

Tags: nginx, websocket

nginx.conf:

```js
http {
  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
          default upgrade;
          '' close;
      }

  ##
  # Basic Settings
  ##

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  # server_tokens off;

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    
    server_name внешний_ip site-q.ru;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
    
    #настройки ssl
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384';    

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8831;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
  }
  ...
```

ssl сертификат и ключ корректно настроены и присутствуют, сайт выложен на домен site-q.ru на рег.ру (там кстати и получил ssl)
есть сервер на отдельном компе, там настроен nginx и запущен websocket сервер - localhost:8831
на клиенте я подключаюсь так: wss://внешний_ip, но идет статус pending и все, потом соединение обрывается, что может быть не так?